# Find Ajax FileUpload Select button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using jquery and asp.net.
I have some outside textboxes that need a value before a user uploads a file. I have elected to do validation upon the user clicking the "select Button". However it is not working. When I click the select button there is no validation prompt. Please help. Below is a piece of code that I got from googling.

```
 $(function () {
    $("#AjaxFileUpload1_InputFileElement").on("click", function () {
        if ($("#CaseTitleTextBox").val().length == 0) {
            alert("description should not empty, please ....");
            //e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is your *actual* code?

Comment: Post some HTML, it is usually helpful